Benefits of Narasimha ashttotara shatanamavali
What are the benefits mentions in Hindu scriptures of the parayana of the Narasimha ashttotara shatanama ? Can it dissolve the major karmic sins done in this life and the previous lives?

Usually stotra have benefits in the end right ? Logical conclusion we can infer. All the deities are spiritually advanced, they are nearer/ merged with supreme. If we pray (via stotra ) with desire of moksha. I think Deity will guide about next path. I  believe that because I don’t  have any guru. Based on Aghori Vimalananda, we need to focus on deity (single). Deity will guide.
